# Big mod algorithm for range 10^18?

Tags: c++, algorithm, number-theory

I have to calculate N^X MOD 10^18+7 and my range is 1<=N,X<=10^18 . Usual big mod algorithm will fail to calculate this . What is the proper algorithm to solve this 
I am using C++ . As the range is 10^18 the lowest mod of 10^18+7 will be 10^18 , if so then the compiler would have to calculate 10^18*10^18 . which will cause an overflow .

Comment: Use a big number library for your language of choice.  Since you don't specify your language or more details, this question will likely be closed as too broad quickly.  Edit and add the extra info before this happens :)

Comment: _"Usual big mod algorithm will fail to calculate this"_. What makes you say that? I think it will work just fine.

Comment: The range is 10^18 . what is the minimum mod of 10^18+7 ? 10^18 . if my both inputs are 10^18 then it will cause an overflow .

Comment: @Kevin No, it won't. To compute n^x%m, you'll have to do a lot of n*n. If m>n>sqrt(2^63-1) this will overflow

Comment: Again, what language?  And floats/doubles may work for you (accuracy dependent), or other systems that are smart about making larger data types.  "Overflow" is an not algorithm or number-theory thing.  It's a language thing.

Comment: I am sorry . Edited . I am using C++ .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a solution that doesn't involve using bignums. The main problem with the trivial solution is the need to compute `n*n`. If `n>sqrt(2^63-1)` that will overflow an `int64` number. The solution to this is to compute `n*n%m` the same way you are computing `n^x%m`.

I mean, you'll have to implement a custom modular multiplication that avoids overflow by only doing additions.

In C++ this would be something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T mmul(T a, T b, T m) {
    a %= m;
    T result = 0;
    while (b) {
        if (b % 2) result = (result + a) % m;
        a = (a + a) % m;
        b /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}

template <typename T>
T mpow(T a, T b, T m) {
    a %= m;
    T result = 1;
    while (b) {
        if (b % 2) result = mmul(result, a, m);
        a = mmul(a, a, m);
        b /= 2;
    }
    return result;
}


int main() {
    long long big = 1000000000000000000;
    cout << mpow(big+1, big+2, big+7) << endl;
}
```